# How to parse json in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i have a **json array** given below.

```
{
 "Success":[
  {
     "auth_id":"3",
     "mobile":"123456789",
     "password":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
     "type":"2",
     "status":"1",
     "last_login":null,
     "student_fullname":"Kirti Yadav ",
     "parent_fullname":null,
     "id":null,
     "pnr_no":"6756787",
     "fname":null,
     "middlename":"mahesh",
     "lname":null,
     "birth_date":"1994-02-07 12:08:55"
  }
]
}
```

how to parse this json array to get **mobile** field.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Success[0].mobile??`

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the native type to represent object in Javascript.

Ionic 2 use Angular 2 (tell me if i'm wrong) so it's Javascript or Typescrit (that's the same about json)

So you can access it easily like this :

```
let obj = {
 "Success":[
  {
     "auth_id":"3",
     "mobile":"123456789",
     "password":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
     "type":"2",
     "status":"1",
     "last_login":null,
     "student_fullname":"Kirti Yadav ",
     "parent_fullname":null,
     "id":null,
     "pnr_no":"6756787",
     "fname":null,
     "middlename":"mahesh",
     "lname":null,
     "birth_date":"1994-02-07 12:08:55"
  }
]
};
console.log(obj.Success[0].mobile);
```

This will output in console :

```
123456789
```

Because mobile = 123456789

Bye :)